# How to submit local apk file to remote appium server?

Tags: android, node.js, appium

**My setup:**

- PC-1
- PC-2

**PC-1:**

- has apk file
- executes appium tests against PC-2

**PC-2:**

- has only nodejs with appium running

**Problem:**
When I want to run a test

```
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: 
A new session could not be created. 
(Original error: Bad app: <<local_path>>myApp.apk. 
App paths need to be absolute, or relative to the appium server install dir, or a URL to compressed file, or a special app name. 
cause: Error: Error locating the app: 
ENOENT, stat '<<local_path>>myApp.apk') (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)

Build info: version: '2.41.0', revision: '3192d8a6c4449dc285928ba024779344f5423c58', time: '2014-03-27 11:29:39'
System info: host: 'my-PC', ip: 'XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_55'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:193)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:145)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:595)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:240)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:126)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:153)
```

**My Caps:**

`caps.setCapability("device","android");
        caps.setCapability("deviceName","Galaxy S3");
        caps.setCapability("platformName","android");
        caps.setCapability("version", "4.3");
        caps.setCapability("deviceType", "phone");
        caps.setCapability(CapabilityType.PLATFORM, "Windows");
        caps.setCapability("app-activity", "package.activities.MyActivity_");
        caps.setCapability("app-package", "xx.my.myapp");
        caps.setCapability("app", app.getAbsolutePath());`

-> So how do I sumbit my local APK file from PC-1 to PC-2 where appium is running?

Comment: Could you provide more information about your environment and build tools?
It is important to know whether you use Maven or Gradle, and do you use Jenkins/Travis/TeamCity for your builds.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So the error you're getting, `Bad App`, is because Appium cannot find the .apk that you gave it in the 'app' capability.

The logs show that you're trying to tell Appium that the app is at: `<>myApp.apk`.

My guess is that your `app.getAbsolutePath()` function is not returning the path to the .apk

Appium is able to download a compressed `.apk` file from a url. If you host the `.apk` on the local network, or network the two computers together somehow, you should be able to point the 'app' capability to that URL.

The test is if you paste the path into your browser window it should take you to download the `.apk`

Comment: you are right - I now using a Url 'http://my-repo/myApk.apk'

- Appium Capability documentation can be found here:
http://appium.io/slate/en/master/?ruby#appium-server-capabilities